# Error: [$injector:unpr] in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to store values from a form using sessionStorage. But it is throwing error,

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=%24sessionStorageProvider%20%3C-%20%24sessionStorage

this is my **app.js** file

```
var BusRegModule = angular.module('BusRegModule', ['ui.router']);

BusRegModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    /* should route to sum.html(below code was used for checking) */
   $stateProvider.state('home', {      
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: 'home.html'
   }); 
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);      
});

BusRegModule.controller('BusRegController',["$scope","$sessionStorage","$http", function($scope,$sessionStorage,$http){
 $scope.storage=$sessionStorage;
 $scope.businessReg=  {}
 $scope.submitMyForm=function() {        
     var q;
     sessionStorage.setItem("q",JSON.stringify($scope.businessReg));
     var d=sessionStorage.getItem("q"); 
     alert(d);
 };
}]);
```

And more doubt also, can anyone give me a simple example to do routing in angular js using $UrlRouterProvider. I want to get values from a form(reg.html) using sessionStorage and need to route to an another page(sum.html) and echo out the values from form(reg.html) there.
The above code have lot of errors, any help would be life saving..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is globally available. You don't need to inject it, nor is it available for injection

Comment: is `sessionStorage` your service?

Comment: Nope, sessionStorage is for getting the values from the form and to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly along with the AngularJS JavaScript file, **ngStorage.min.js** file also needs to be inherited in order to perform operations on HTML5 LocalStorage and SessionStorage objects.
Then you need to pass ngStorage parameter in angular.module definition and then inject the $localStorage, $sessionStorage dependency in the controller.

Here is an example on how to save and get the data to and from the sessionStorage. Here i have two functions

1. to save data to sessionStorage
2. to get data

   ```
   var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
   app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
       $scope.Save = function () {
           $sessionStorage.SessionMessage = "SessionStorage: Storing some data.";
       }
       $scope.Get = function () {
           $window.alert($sessionStorage.SessionMessage);
       }
   });
   ```

   I hope this helps :)